# How can I execute a simple jar?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to make a simple batch file with maven commands to execute the installation and execute the jar main class.

But the compile JAR does not have the dependencies and I get error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   akka/actor/ActorSystem

This is my simple script

```
call mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies
call mvn package
call cd target
call java -jar distributed-1.0.0.jar
pause
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>distributed</groupId>
    <artifactId>distributed</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java/resources/lib
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source/>
                    <target/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.ipca.distributed.Implementations</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What do I need here??

Comment: Take a look at the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

Comment: Make sure MANIFEST.MF points your `lib` directory

Comment: @Valijon in my manifest I have this `Main-Class: com.foo.distributed.Implementations`

Comment: Post your MANIFEST.MF content. Make sure `Class-Path:` has path to `akka-actor_2.11-2.5.16.jar` etc... file

Comment: I only have that line in my MANIFEST.MF

Comment: any help??????????

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution to create a runnable jar is to use [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), or [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), or [One Jar Plugin](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-create-a-fat-jar-file-one-jar-example/) or even [Spring Boot Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) ( it's not weird if it works ). You can find some more details on how to use each one [here](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven).

These plugins are doing exactly you are trying to do with the 2 combined plugins that you have ( maven-dependency-plugin and maven-jar-plugin ).